# Inequality $ab\le \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $\frac {1}{p}+\frac {1}{q}=1$ and $a,b \ge 0$ , then prove $ab\le \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$ . I can't find a simple and short way to prove this. Any hint would work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is called Young's inequality. It is equivalent to showing $a^{1/p}b^{1/q} \le \frac1{p} a + \frac1{q}b$, which follows from the convexity of $\ln$ (supposing that $a,b > 0$; the other case is trivial)

Comment: this is the inequality of Young

Comment: @ahemd thank you very much for your hint.

Comment: you can prove this using the AM-GM inequality as well

Comment: @clark I was trying but i wan not able to prove. Can you explain how ?

Comment: @VineetMangal You prove this firstly for $p,q$ rational numbers and then you say it is true for every number by density

Comment: I think the [proof here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259826/purely-algebraic-proof-of-youngs-inequality) is short and elegant!

Comment: @awllower that was a wonderful proof. But i also got one good proof on wikipedia. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @VineetMangal that proof does exactly what I suggested

Comment: @clark thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Some  other related posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149901/geometric-interpretation-of-youngs-inequality and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259102/youngs-inequality-without-using-convexity

Answer (score 4):

The [general theorem of means](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1788730/72031) (perhaps more popularly known as Young's inequality as the comment to this answer suggests) implies that if $x, y, r, s$ are positive with $r + s = 1$ then $$x^{r}y^{s} \leq rx + sy\tag{1}$$ Putting $x = a^{p}, y = b^{q}, r = 1/p, s = 1/q$ we get $$ab \leq \frac{a^{p}}{p} + \frac{b^{q}}{q}$$

Comment: -1 It is called Young's inequality, not general theorem of means; the latter term does not show up in any google search. Please do not use non-standard terminology when referring to theorems (If I am wrong tell me and I'll happily revert my downvote)

Comment: @Ant The inequality he refers to is generally called the weighted AM-GM inequality. I guess the other name is a translation of the name in the OP's native language. (It would probably be a good idea to change this in the post)

Comment: @Ant: Thanks for your comment. I strongly dislike the fashion of giving downvote without comment and you are an exception to this. It means a great deal here. The terminology is not standard and I have got this from Hardy's "A Course of Pure Mathematics".  I will add your terminology also in the answer.

Comment: @Ant: Its so bad everyone here is not like you. I have now received a downvote without any explanation (and yes I know you had reversed yours). That's why I said your comment means a great deal. I wonder why people don't explain their downvote.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment and learn something from users like Ant?